# Selecting several disseminate features with ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, select, feature-layer

I have a cadastral map similar to this one from an ArcGIS Javascript API example:

[Cadastral map](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/samples/query_deferred_list/index.html)

What I would like to do is selecting several parcels clicking on them and show the information related in a sidebar or floating panel. For example, I would like to select that big house on the right side and then few more spread on the map. Every time I click on one, I would like the application to show the information associated **AND** not losing that selection when clicking on a new one. In the end, I should have an array of selected features (or similar) that maybe I can re-use later.

I have tried [Feature Layer with Selection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/samples/fl_selectfeatures/index.html) example, but it does not fully fit my requirements, because depending on the distance between features, I can't select two of them without selecting many more that I do not need.

Is this possible? Can anyone explain the process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want to select features and not clear the selection graphics layer each time you click a feature. If you're using a FeatureLayer, you would use SELECTION_ADD instead of SELECTION_NEW to add the selected features as you click on them.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for! If anyone a part of ADD features, also have to SUBTRACT features, here there is an example I found to do these operations with "click" and "Shift+Click". [http://jsfiddle.net/J4sfK/](http://jsfiddle.net/J4sfK/) Pretty useful! Thanks @raykendo!

Comment: data on fiddle was broken. here it is updated with states data http://jsfiddle.net/J4sfK/36/